# Grid with fixed number of lines and rows, overflow

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid with 3 columns and 6 rows. Inside this grid there are dynamic elements, they can take differents size. But I want my grid to take the height of the screen when the elements are within the 3 columns and 6 rows. If one element does not enters in the grid, I want it to go beneath the other elements, while the other elements doesn't move. Is it possible using CSS grid ?

In this exemple item4 and item5 should be under item2

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item1, .item2 {
  grid-row: span 3 / span 3;
  grid-column: span 2 / span 2;
}

.item3, .item4, .item5 {
  grid-row: span 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure this is possible with CSS Grid Level 1 (current implementation). Have you considered `grid-auto-flow: dense`?  https://jsfiddle.net/wd9a6hpo/

Comment: Yes but I do not want this behavior, items 1 to 3 are placed correctly in my example.

Comment: I understand. Just presenting you an option that *may* have been useful, otherwise I"m not sure your desired layout is possible with CSS alone.

Answer (score 1):

I was not sure what you were trying to accomplish, because based on your current CSS, your grid would not fill the web page. So here is just something your might try.

### SOLUTION

1. Always set your `<html>` and `<body>` tags to use full height of the *viewport* using CSS otherwise your grid will not fill the page. (see HTML below)
2. Always make sure your grid `<div>` or other HTML inside body also uses the full height using CSS or your grid will now fill the page. Btw...I recommend you set the `<body>` tag as the grid parent, as it will guarantee full page width and height much better :)
3. In Grids, you have to make a choice between row vs column in your logic for how to fill the page. If you don't, the browser does not know which takes precedence when there is not enough cells to fill the space and will make a guess based on your parent grid logic. In the example below, I set rows as the space to fill the window using `auto-fit`. It says to fit everything in the grid vertically by rows but remove any extra space that refuses to fill that vertical space. This gives your grid full window height and width.
4. You indicated use of 6 rows, but are not using them based on your logic. So there is no need for that as the design below will allow you to add or remove any number of child cells and create new rows as needed. They will all share the vertical space as rows, which is what stretches to fill the browser window now.
5. In the design below, you can add or remove an unlimited number of new cells and they are always included in the full browsers *viewport* space.

This design will always *grow* or *shrink* to fill the browser *viewport*. **In the first example it stacks by rows vertically**, creating new rows as cells are added. In the last code example, it would **stack by column**, adding cells horizontally until 3 columns are filled, then start a new row.

All examples fill the *viewport* of the browser window 100% by both width and height.

```
<!doctype html>
<html style="width:100%;height:100%;">
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;">

<style type="text/css">

.container {
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto-fit;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
}

.container div[class^=item] {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background:green;
}

</style>
 
 <div class="container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
</div>
<!-- I added this cell to show how items not part of the grid CSS stack under the full viewport grid. -->
<div>6</div>
```

If you want the cells to stack into the available columns one at a time horizontally instead of rows, but still allow the rows to grow as new cells are added into the browser *viewport* space, remove the "grid-column" logic, as below. The blocks will now stack into the available space horizontally. **This probably demonstrates what you are trying to achieve best**, as it fills the browser space going down, allowing new cells to stack horizontally one at a time onto the grid while the other cells do not change. The other cells would not move, only grow thinner vertically as new rows get created to hold more cells. Again, no matter how many cells are used, the full *viewport* of the browser window is used. Since you are using a 3-column design, however, until 3 columns fill the last row, spaces will appear since you are using a 3-column layout.

```
.container div[class^=item] {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background:green;
}
```